# sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4 with Sonar 4.5.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am using Sonar 4.5.1 and sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4 to run the build. PDF report is not getting generated an is showing below message : Internal error: Can't retrieve project info. Parent project node is empty. Authentication?. 
I saw a bug posted for this (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3854) but would like to know what is the workaround available for this issue.  User Authentication is already set for this in General Settings->Pdf report but doesn't work either.

Comment: May I have a reply on this please? I read that this bug is resolved in 1.4.1 milestone (https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report/issues/14). Where can I find the download for sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4.1 download ? Please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in commit [a49b8f61afbf47b5f7976d0a759cb0efcd6c5bce](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report/commit/a49b8f61afbf47b5f7976d0a759cb0efcd6c5bce).

For now you cannot download jar with this fix, but you can download sources and build custom version:

- fetch sources (by `git clone https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report.git` or [download zip](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report/archive/master.zip))
- execute maven command `mvn clean install`
- copy generated jar to `sonar/data/extensions/plugins`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply  and it worked! I also would like to confirm as the jar is not yet available , I hope the generated jar from sources will not have any other impact on the builds